# Make different div within different class in the same line

Tags: css, drupal, cck

I have something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper" style="display:block;">
  <div class="field1">
    <div class="label">Label1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="field2">
    <div class="label">Label2</div>
    <div class="item">Item2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="field3">
    <div class="label">Label3</div>
    <div class="item">Item3</div>
  </div>

  ... more fields ...
</div>
```

How can I have my display shown as "Item1 Item2 Item3" in the same line by CSS? I can hide the label by "display:none;". I'm using Drupal 7 and CCK fields, so I think the structure is kinda fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you have a wrapper that must be set to display:block, but inside it you'd like each div on the same line.

In that case, this CSS should do it for you:

```
.field1, .field2, .field3 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Here it is in [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jjQdT/3/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also found out my newbie mistake that I had other CSS code position:absolute; make it not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want everything on one line, you should use `span`s.

Specifically, if you want

> Item1 Item2 Item3

then use

```
<span class="field1">
    <span class="label">Label1</span>
    <span class="item">Item 1</span>
</span>
<!-- ... -->
```

Also, you don't need the quotations: `<span class=field1></span>` is fine.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Know this is old, but there's no reason you shouldn't use quotes